# CSS - Target 3rd div but skip Child Divs

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, css-selectors, parent-child

I am working with a WordPress plugin so I am unable to add a class on the PHP side seeing as this plugin receives and update every week and would override my changes. I need to try to do this on the front end.

Here is the code:

```css
.mainInfo div:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: #302b44;
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
  padding: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainInfo">
  <div>This is the 1st Div
    <div>Lorem ipsum.</div>
    <div>Quis, reiciendis.</div>
    <div>Repudiandae, inventore!</div>
  </div>
  <div>This is the 2nd Div
    <div>Lorem ipsum.</div>
    <div>Voluptates, minima.</div>
    <div>Minima, assumenda?</div>
  </div>
  <div>This is the 3rd Div **The only one I want to select**
    <div>Lorem ipsum.</div>
    <div>Dolores, ullam!</div>
    <div>Sequi, eligendi!</div>
  </div>
  <div>This is the 4th Div
    <div>Lorem ipsum.</div>
    <div>Recusandae, commodi.</div>
    <div>Reiciendis, nostrum.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/agon024/1s9v20y7/22/) showing what I am trying to accomplish, but what I'm sure you already know is this is also counting the child DIVs inside the main parent DIVs also. I only want to target the 3rd "main" DIV inside of "mainInfo" is there a way to accomplish this by skipping the child DIvs? If this can be solved by jQuery I will accept that also.

FYI: Like I said this a WP plugin so the first and second main DIV have varying amounts of child DIVs inside based on user inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `>` selector ([CSS selectors reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)), which forces to select direct childs.

```
.mainInfo > div:nth-of-type(3) {
```

> Selects all "div:nth-of-type(3)" elements where the parent is a ".mainInfo" element

```css
.mainInfo > div:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: #302b44;
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
  padding: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainInfo">
  <div>This is the 1st Div
    <div>Lorem ipsum.</div>
    <div>Quis, reiciendis.</div>
    <div>Repudiandae, inventore!</div>
  </div>
  <div>This is the 2nd Div
    <div>Lorem ipsum.</div>
    <div>Voluptates, minima.</div>
    <div>Minima, assumenda?</div>
  </div>
  <div>This is the 3rd Div **The only one I want to select**
    <div>Lorem ipsum.</div>
    <div>Dolores, ullam!</div>
    <div>Sequi, eligendi!</div>
  </div>
  <div>This is the 4th Div
    <div>Lorem ipsum.</div>
    <div>Recusandae, commodi.</div>
    <div>Reiciendis, nostrum.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the "direct child" connection between both selectors:

```
.mainInfo > div:nth-of-type(3) {
```

That way it does not match grandchildren of `.mainInfo`.